# ValueError while trying to get values every 4 horus from .loc pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following
[image: DataFrame]

I'm trying to get the data every 4 hours from the dataframe using .loc. But its giving me `ValueError` from it

```
df.loc[(df['time'].dt.hour in [0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20]), 'EURUSD_Open']
```

I would be grateful for some help

Comment: Please include any relevant information [as text directly into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), do not link or embed external images of source code or data. Images make it difficult to efficiently assist you as they cannot be copied and offer poor usability as they cannot be searched. See: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15497888)

Comment: If you need assistance formatting a small sample of your DataFrame for SO see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/15497888).

Comment: All of that said, I'd say you were probably looking for something like `df['time'].dt.hour.isin([0,4,8....])`

Comment: Sorry for my mistakes Henry, thank you very much for your help it worked :)